# Why can't we open links in Electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, electron

This is not a question, but I found a solution for the links in the Electron framework.
I've changed the href of the  tag, and set up, if the `target="_blank"`, it opens the default browser and load up the current requested website.

But I got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lolj.png)

I thought, node just doesn't support async and  await functions and Promises without try-catch. I made a try-catch block, same error. Removed the async function, same error. Removed the Promise, same error. Then I gave up, continued creating the html tags.
Then I encountered another link, which opened the browser. I expected the same error, but it turns out, **if the link doesn't have the http:// or https:// prefix, Electron quits with an error.**
So be sure to check the links before changing the href.

I hope I helped anyone.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question

Comment: I mean, I made a discovery, and wanted to show it. Feel free to close this question.

Comment: you can always ask a question and self-answer it. that would be more appropriate

Comment: thank you, i'll do that way in the future